# Reduce number of database queries, initiated from django "for loops" in templates - Django website extremely Slow

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm facing difficulties optimizing the load time of my website. I installed Django Debug Toolbar to see from where my 3 to 4 seconds request delays come from. The fact is that it comes from many duplicated SQL Queries.

Recently, I optimized my view code so there is no query duplication, but the essential part of these comes from my template rendering, especially from my for loops (which are everywhere, sadly).

Here is an example:

- This page shows Transactions, divided in several sections. It is paginated by 48. Because of the organization of my template, I'm forced to "for loop" every transaction linked to the user in each category and do some if/elif/else treatments.
- From what I saw by removing 5 of the 6 for loops, it reaches my RDS database EVERY TIME a for loop is started, which does not sound efficient, and takes forever to load.

I've seen some caching methods out there but I don't know if my case applies for such thing.

Comment: Please put links into your question, by editing it (and code should be contained within the question itself - there is both a JS code runner and a block code formatter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) when you follow related objects.

> This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex
>   query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
>   database queries.

You are following related objects all over in your templates, for example `offer` and `(offer.)thing`. If you include s`elect_related('offer', 'offer__thing')` in your queryset, you will significantly reduce numbers of queries.

For your future reference, look also into following relationships with [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). It's not relevant in your case, but keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I got 1 sec less in my loading time (from 5.3s to 4s). Is there a way to cache `transaction.status` so it doesn't have to fetch it again. Or can I cache/prefetch the entire transaction queryset (which returns all my transactions) ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Static fields were not causing me troubles, it was ForeignKey queries that delayed my page loads. You were RIGHT and I can't be more thankful.

Comment: For e.g, this exact 'View Transactions' page took 4.7sec to  load before, now it takes just 450ms. That's amazing !